# passing to another loop in python

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, continue

```
word1 = 'index.php/1'
word2 = 'index.php/2'
try:        
    tentativa1 = urllib2.urlopen(site + word1)
    tentativa2 = urllib2.urlopen(site + word2)

except URLError as e:
    tentativa1 = e
    tentativa2 = e

lista = [tentativa1, tentativa2]
    for website in lista:
     if website.code == 200:
        website = website.read()
        print '\n:)' if 'registration' in website else '\n:/'
        print '\n:)' if 'there is no form' in website else '\n:/'
```

the idea is to "continue" the code after the first "if". How can I do it?

Comment: Uhh python has the standard continue keyword if thats what you are wanting.. http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-continue-statement

Comment: It's a bit confusing what you want to do. Can you elaborate?

Comment: schwiz: I don't get how to use "continue" ><!

Comment: Steinar: The project is to input a website and the code will find "keywords" inside the source code by using the ".read()" but I don't know how to pass the first "if tentativa1.code" to the "tentativa2.code"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I want to say that your question is very unclear.  Hence, most of this answer is guesswork.

However, when I read your post/comments, I got an idea that you want something like this:

```
lst = [tentativa1, tentativa2]
for item in lst:
    if item.code == 200:
        item = item.read()
        print '\n:)' if 'registration' in item else '\n:/'
        print '\n :)' if 'there is no form' in item else '\n:/'
```

Also, [`continue`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-continue-statement) is used to jump to the top of the nearest enclosing for/while loop.  Meaning, you would not use it here because that functionality is not required.

Comment: Sorry about it :~! I'm tried and hasn't worked. I updated the code. I think my mistake is because "tentativa1" and "tentativa2" are the same website.

Comment: There's no error, just don't print :X!

Answer (score 0):

may be you can use a flag variable set to some value inside the first if statement. and then check for that value to continue the rest of the code.

```
SetFlag=0

if tentativa1.code == 200:
    SetFlag=1
    if 'registration' in tentativa1.read():
        print '\n:)'

 else:

    print '\n:/'

if (SetFlag==1):

   if tentativa2.code == 200:
          if 'there is no form' in tentativa2.read():
          print '\n :)'

      else:
          print '\n:/'
```

Comment: I don't get it, can you show me?

Comment: if tentativa1.code == 200:
    SetFlag=1
    if 'registration' in tentativa1.read():
        print '\n:)'

    else:
        print '\n:/'

if (SetFlag==1):
 
 rest of ur code

Comment: shit, I'm trying but isn't working :~. Update your major comment with your code.

Comment: I tried but hasn't printed :/. I updated the code*